# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component_2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a .net web base application that use MSSQL Reporting service(SSRS) to make reports.
when i make a report and i want to EXPORT my report as PDF file I get this error:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
```

Note that i can export other file types BUT PDF.
I tried RUN->dcomcnfg.exe->Component services -> .. but no effence.it does't work for me (:

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: UNFORTUNATELY not yet

Comment: In my case, this error comes only when I want to print Bar-code in report file.
Still, I am not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Your Reports on another Server and Set your report server URL again,
it was very useful for me.
Try it.
:)